# % based, fixed and absolute positioned, nested elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Image: 
[image]
I have a **container div (yellow)** which I’d like to keep at 50% width of the window. A child of that container is an **image div (purple)** that stretches to 100% of the parent container’s width. and there’s a **sticky label (pink)** on top of the image div (position: absolute so it can be offset relatively to the image). *I'd like to keep that entire half of the screen fixed positioning* so it stays sticky as I scroll.

There’s also a title under the image, and that title needs to be visible no matter if someone shrinks the window vertically. So in that scenario the *image div* should shrink vertically, if needed, in order for that title to be shown.

Basically I'm trying to have the image div always be 100% *width* of the parent *container div*. With the image div having a *max % height* so it can shrink vertically. Or have it keep a fixed aspect ratio (3:4 or whatever) when it shrinks vertically.

I'm trying to avoid using fixed pixels, or ems, in the entirety of my CSS. since the website needs to be stretchy/‘fluid’ vertically, because that title under the image has to show.

HTML looks roughly like:

```
<wrapper>
    <left-column>
        <normal text and scrollable stuff>
    <right-column-yellow>
        <image sticky label-pink>
        <image div-purple>
        <image title>
```

Sorry if this is damn confusing my brain is fried! Can anyone pls help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can divide your left and right panel by using position fixed.

If I'm not wrong with your description, this is the answer.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
   <p><!--Some very long text--></p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="image">
    <div class="label">Label</div>
    <div class="title">Title</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Some CSS

```
.left,.right{
    position: fixed;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .left{
    left:0;
    top: 0;
    overflow: auto;
  }

  .right{
    right: 0;
    top:0;
    background-color: yellow;
  }

  .right .image{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }

  .right .image .label{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: -10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: pink;
    margin: auto;
  }

  .right .image .title{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -40px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #000;
    margin: auto;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
```

You can refer to my codeine as well.
https://codepen.io/masonwongcs/pen/WMJGZb

Comment: That's awesome! Completely didn't think of using both sides as fixed. Great solution. 

Would using an all-fixed layout like this present problems? Is it commonplace?

Comment: It depends on which kind of layout you want to achieve. In this case I think it will be alright.